# Compare two lists which are values in a dict and return which has the min val in the list Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict like this

`b =  {'2': ['10', '5', '4'], '4': ['1', '9', '2'], '3': ['90', '87', '77'], '1': ['30']}`

I need to compare each value in the list to others and return only the least value in the dict

I have tried

```
for k,v in b.items():
  for r in range(len(v)):
    print(min(v[r] + v[r]))
```

It is giving me a weird output!
This is the output obtained from that code.

```
0
5
4
1
9
2
0
7
7
0
0
0
0
```

I need the key and value which has the least value in the entire dict output like this `d = {4:[1]}`

Comment: Are you looking for the min val?, `min(b)` would do

Comment: yeas I'm looking for the min val

Comment: What values should ich value in the list be compared against?
"least " did you mean "last"?

Comment: I need the key and value not just the value Thanks! @CIsForCookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly one-liner:

```
b =  {'2': ['10', '5', '4'], '4': ['1', '9', '2'], '3': ['90', '87', '77'], '1': ['30']}
result = dict([min(((int(k), [min(map(int, v))]) for k, v in b.items()), key=lambda t: t[1])])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{4: [1]}
```

Breakdown:

```
b =  {'2': ['10', '5', '4'], '4': ['1', '9', '2'], '3': ['90', '87', '77'], '1': ['30']}

# Generator of each key with its minimal element
# (here the generator would produce the list [(2, [4]), (4, [1]), (3, [77]), (1, [30])])
key_min = ((int(k), [min(map(int, v))]) for k, v in b.items())
# Pick tuple with minimal value
# (here the tuple (4, [1]) from the previous generator)
min_entry = min(key_min, key=lambda t: t[1])
# Make into dict
# (here {4: [1]}; first element of the tuple is the key and second element the value)
result = dict([min_entry])
print(result)
```

Comment: +1 for actually trying to explain your answer (and admitting it's ugly) although I suspect @user9538877 will still struggle to understand, it's not clear to me they know they have strings but they seem to want to compare/output integers

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are right, it is probably still confusing for someone starting with Python. Please @user9538877 do let know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a dict-comprehension

```
 {int(key): [min( int(value) for value in value_list)] for key, value_list in b.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: this will get all the key values with values as list of min value from the list of integers. op probably wants to narrow it down to the smallest pair from these as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a straightforward answer without any confusion

```
min_list = {}
for k,v in b.items():
    min_value = min(v)
    min_list[min_value] = k

print({ min_list[min(min_list)]:min(min_list)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You want the minimum of minimums, or:

```
min({k: min(b[k], key=int) for k in b}.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

This returns the tuple `('4', '1')`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

First, your list is numbers as text. I did not correct that. If you can fix that then you can take off the in() in this code.

```
 for k, v in b.items():
    x = int(min(b[k]))
    try:
        lowVal
    except:
        lowVal = x
        lowKey = k
    else:
        if x < lowVal:
            lowKey = k
            lowVal = x
 print('{0}: {1}'.format(lowKey, lowVal))
```

1. Step through each item in the dict
2. find the lowest value and make it an int() and set to x for convenience
3. try to see if this is our first time through, if it is set the key to lowKey and the lowest value in the list to lowVal
4. Otherwise if lowVal already exists see if the current lowest value in the list is lower than the previous lowest. If it is then set lowKey and lowVal to the current loops values
5. Print
6. ????
7. Profit

Edit: a word

Answer (score 0):

What if you have multiple key value pairs with same minimum value?

This solution works fine for that as well.

```
result={k:min(map(int,v)) for k,v in b.items()}
minVal=min(result.values())
result={k:[minVal] for k in result.iterkeys()  if result[k] == minVal}
print(result)
{'4': [1]}
```

for ex :

`b = {'2': ['10', '5', '4'], '4': ['1', '9', '2'], '3': ['90', '1', '77'], '1': ['30']}`

Output will be :

```
{'3': [1], '4': [1]}
```